# CAKEPHP: Completely different behaviour for an online webapplication

Tags: cakephp

I have a link like `http://www.myweb.it/people/add/` when execute I have problem about   non-existent `add` view and json:

> Error: The view for PeopleController::add() was not found.
>
> Error: Confirm you have created the file: /var/datas/httpd/vhosts/myweb.it/demo/htdocs/0.4/app/View/elements/json.ctp

The problem is that imported file are correctly handled in local.
This is the entire people controller:

```
<?php
class PeopleController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'People';
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

        public function add() {
        $this->autorender = false;

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Person->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->set('return', 'I dati sono stati salvati.');
            } else {
                $this->set('return', 'Non è stato possibile salvare i dati.');
            }
        }

        $this->layout = 'void';
        $this->render('/elements/json');
    }

    public function getPeopleByName(){
        $people = $this->Person->getPeopleByName($_GET['name']);
        $this->set(array(
            'People' => $people,
            '_serialize' => array('People')
        ));
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is _json.ctp_ used as a layout, view...?

Comment: Does the file exist on your server?

Comment: I repeat, this code works on localhost.

Comment: you need to post the code to be reviewed without code it's impossible to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `$this->render('/elements/json');` should be `$this->render('/Elements/json');`, at least if your element is placed in CakePHP's default location for elements, which is `app/View/Elements`.

Comment: Probably you are right! Local environment is a windows machine, while online in 99,999% is a Unix, and so case-sensitive, server. I'll let you now as soon I can update the code. Thank you in advice